# Actionscript 3.0 use Math.random()

Tags: actionscript-3

Actionscript to use Math.random what will this mean Right = 6 + Math.random() * 2;

I know Math.random is between 0-0.99... but will it come out (6 - 7)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Math.random * 2 is going to be a value between 0 and 2. If you add 6 to that you get a number such that 6 <= n and n < 8.

Answer (score 3):

`Math.random()` returns a number greater or equal to 0 and less than 1.0, i.e.

`0 <= Math.random() < 1.0`

If we multiply this with `b` then we get a number greater or equal to 0 and less than b, i.e.

`(0 * b) <= (Math.random() * b) < (1.0 * b)`

or `0 <= (Math.random() * b) < b`

If we add `a` with this then we get a number greater or equal to `a` and less than `a + b`, i.e.

`(a + 0) <= (a + Math.random() * b) < (a + b)`

or `a <= (a + Math.random() * b) < (a + b)`

So, `6 + Math.random() * 2` returns a number greater or equal to 6 and less than 8. If you assign this to an integer then it will be either 6 or 7.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to write a function to set the scale and range for you.  Like this:

```
public static function getRandomNumber(low:Number=0, high:Number=1):Number
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (1+high-low)) + low;
}
```

Now you can call it:

```
getRandomNumber(6, 7); //returns 6-7 inclusive
```